# Bins and Balls problem Expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, balls-in-bins

**Question** : Suppose that n balls are tossed into b bins so that each
ball is equally likely to fall into any of the bins and that
the tosses are independent.

c) What is the expected number of balls tossed until a
particular bin contains a ball?

d) What is the expected number of balls tossed until all
bins contain a ball?

**My work:**

For part (c), I defined a new indicator r.v $X_i$ which takes the value $1$ if all the previous $i$ balls didn't go into the bin and $0$ otherwise. Then it follows that the number of balls tossed until a particular bin contains a ball  is:

$X=X_1+X_2+...+X_n+1$. Therefore $E(X)=1+\sum_{i=1}^n{E(X_i)}$. We know that $E(X_i)$ is the expectation that all i balls don't go into that particular bin so we have: $E(X_i)=(\frac{b-1}{b})^i$. So $E(X)=1+\sum_{i=1}^n{E(X_i)}=1+\sum_{i=1}^n{(\frac{b-1}{b})^i}=\sum_{i=0}^n{(\frac{b-1}{b})^i}=b(1-(\frac{b-1}{b})^n)$. Any problems with the answer so far?

(d) I am lost with this one, any hints on a suitable r.v?

Comment: Part $d$ is the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Thanks, I just checked the Wikipedia page and I think I get it. Also, do you think there is any problem with my answer of (c)?

Comment: For c, just think of it as a binomial process.  Each toss is either a success or a failure, success meaning that your favorite bin gets the ball.  The probability of success on a particular trial is $\frac 1b$, so the answer is $b$.

Comment: But doesn't your answer assume that this is a geometric distribution when it is not? Since we have only n balls so we eventually HAVE to stop if we don't reach  success? For example, if I take the limit of my answer to infinity, it gives me b, however, n is finite here no?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming large $n$.  If $n$ is finite...what does expectation mean?  You  want $E=\sum_{i=1}^n i\left(\frac {b-1}b\right)^{i-1}\frac 1b$?

Comment: Just to be clear, your method assigns the answer $n+1$ to the case where all the balls miss the given bin.  In the limit that works fine, because there's a vanishing chance that we keep on missing the bin, but it is not exact.

Comment: Aha, I see. Can you explain how you derived the expectation equation you wrote? I am not sure what's going on there?

Comment: I didn't derive it...that's the definition.  Well, if you replace $n$ with $\infty$ then that's the definition.  In general $E=\sum ip(i)$ where $p(i)$ is the probability that it takes $i$ tosses.  It's unusual to speak about an expected number of trials until an event might occur when it's possible the event will never occur. If you meant something different than the truncated expectation, you should include your own definition.

Comment: That's what confuses me. The question asks for the expectation this event might happen when it might never even happen!

Comment: Well, I think my definition is the only one that makes sense (though of course someone else might have a different notion).  You can adapt your method to do my sum...yours equals mine $+(n+1)p(>n)$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. I think I will ask my professor to clarify more on this problem, but I think I get the gist of this. Have a nice day (or night).

Comment: Sorry, just one last thing I am making sure of, Your said yours equals mine $+(n+1)p(>n)$, do you mean by this: $+ \sum_{i=n+1}^{\inf} ip(i)$ ??

Comment: No.  My formula assigns the value $0$ to all the tosses after the first $n$, you assign the value $n+1$.  Neither is part of the ordinary definition of expectation...I think mine is more natural, but it's just a definition and we can set it how we like. As you say, you should ask what was intended.